# Where can I find all possible outputs of certain github commands?

Tags: git, github

The title is as simple as it seems; I'm trying to make a prompt for my terminal and that will display all of the information about the current branch. While I could just create all of the scenarios manually, I'm confused about the format of certain commands; for example, if `git status -sb` says a branch is 3 up, and 0 behind; I know it will say `[3 ahead`, but will it show `0 behind]`, or simply nothing? I am most likely parsing the output of these commands, so it is pretty vital to know. Is there a certain site that shows this, or will I have to create the scenarios on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am most likely parsing the output of these commands

Don't do that. Those commands are "porcelain", they're human-convenience renditions of the underlying data, and they're explicitly not made for scraping. As the people who work on Git find more convenient ways to work, the convenience commands will be updated. The core command outputs won't change. Guaranteed. The convenience commands all started as scripts based on core commands and could still be done that way.

To take your example, ~how many ahead, how many behind~, you can get those numbers directly, with

```
base=`git merge-base @{u} @`
ahead=`git rev-list --count $base..@`
behind=`git rev-list --count $base..@{u}`
echo $ahead ahead, $behind behind `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}`
```

`@{u}` is shorthand for `HEAD@{upstream}` and `@` is shorthand for `HEAD`.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to ask about a better way to do that as well. However, in the case you gave, and if possible to generalize for other commands, would those numbers be 0 or nothing if a branch is caught up? I'm just asking this because I  would like to make my prompt appear fast as possible, and I don't want to show 0s in my prompt (I would have to check if each variable was a 0 if so, then remove it).

Comment: Core command outputs won't change, so you can simply try it once and rely on the result in your own scripts forever. Also, memoize your results based on ID's, ID history is immutable, and that's not something anyone even *can* change. So the ahead-behind for any `git rev-parse @ @{u}` result can't change either.